# c#, calculate element in a list

Tags: c#, list, addition

```
private void btnAjouter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double sommeFinale = 0;
    int prixItem;
    int quantité;
    int.TryParse(lstQuantité.Text, out quantité);
    int.TryParse(txtPrix.Text, out prixItem);
    Article unArticle = new Article(lstNuméro.Text, lstArticle.Text, prixItem, quantité);
    lstAffichageArticle.Items.Add(String.Format("{0, -5}{1, -50}{2, -10}{3, -10}",lstNuméro.Text, lstArticle.Text, lstQuantité.Text, txtPrix.Text));
    lblAffCoût.Text = string.Format("{0:n0}", unArticle.CalculerCoûtArt() + unArticle.CalculerCoûtArt());
}
```

I want to be able to sum every `unArticle.CalculerCoûtArt()` from a list and show the result `sommeFinale` in the label `lblAffCoût`.

`unArticle.CalculerCoûtArt` is `prixItem * quantité`.

Comment: Maybe something like `var sum = lstAffichageArticle.Items.Sum(x => x.CalculerCoûtArt());`

Comment: It won't work, `lstAffichageArticle.Items` are not of type `Article`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `List<Article>` populated with all the "articles", then you can try :

```
var sommeFinale = theList.Sum(article => article.CalculerCoûtArt());
lblAffCoût.Text = sommeFinale.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the code is obscured a bit for me by the language barrier (French?). But I believe this is a handler for adding an item to a shopping cart, and you want to calculate the total price including the new item. I think you need to keep a list of the shopping cart items on the server side, and recalculate the price each postback. It could be in the database or a Session object, or various other places. Then loop through the items and calculate the sum.